# Readonly table permissions not applying to new tables

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgreSQL-11 database that get's a new table created every Monday as part of a DW load.  However, when that new table is created, the [readonly] role that's been created doesn't get SELECT permissions to it.  Doesn't seem to matter what I do.  Here are the details:

- Using PostgreSQL 11.6
- RedHat 4.8.5 x64
- Tables are being created in the public schema
- The users that have been created authenticate through LDAP.
- The users are configured to inherit perms from [readonly]

Code used to create acct:

```
CREATE ROLE readonly;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydatabase TO readonly;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonly;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly;

create role user1 login;
GRANT readonly TO user1;
```

Output of \du

```
     Role name  |                 Attributes        | Member of
 ---------------|-----------------------------------|-----------
 dba1           | Superuser, Create role, Create DB | {}
 user1          |                                   | {readonly}
 user2          |                                   | {readonly}
 user3          |                                   | {readonly}
 dba2           | Superuser, Create role, Create DB | {}
 user4          |                                   | {readonly}
 user5          |                                   | {readonly}
 dba3           | Superuser, Create role, Create DB | {}
 appUser        | Create DB                         | {}
 readonly       | Cannot login                      | {}
```

output of \ddp

\ddp output:

```
  Owner    | Schema | Type  | Access privileges
-----------+--------+-------+-------------------  
user1       | public | table | readonly=r/user1  
DBA1        | public | table | =r/DBA1         
            |        |       | DBA1=r/DBA1     
            |        |       | dba2=r/DBA1     
            |        |       | dba3=r/DBA1     
            |        |       | user2=r/DBA1    
            |        |       | user3=r/DBA1    
            |        |       | user4=r/DBA1    
            |        |       | user5=r/DBA1    
            |        |       | user1=r/DBA1    
            |        |       | readonly=r/DBA1
```

**Articles I've used to setup and/or troubleshoot the issue:**

- [Managing PostgreSQL users and roles](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/managing-postgresql-users-and-roles/)
- [Messing with PostgreSQL users and permissions](https://marcyes.com/2016/0922-messing-with-postgresql-users-and-permissions/)
- [ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)

Anyone see what wrong here?  I'm at my wits end and about to give them damn RO user Superuser rights, which is clearly not ideal.

Comment: You seem to have used `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` incorrectly.  Since you didn't show us what you did, we don't know what you did wrong.  You should show us  `\ddp` in addition to `\du`, but better yet what commands you ran, and which user was logged in at the time.  And which user is the one creating these new tables?

Comment: @jjanes

update the original quest with the requested data since formatting is terrible in the comments.

Comment: What you show in \ddp should work, as long as it is either user1 or DBA1 creating the tables.  It won't work for anyone else creating tables.

Comment: @jjanes neither of those accounts are creating tables.  It the appuser is what is creating tables.

Comment: Then you have to do an ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES as/for each of those users.

Comment: @jjanes.  Sorry, not following what you are saying.  Forgive me if I'm being dense.

Comment: @jjanes, can you clarify what you mean here?  Sorry that I'm not following.

Comment: The default privileges take effect on a per-creation-user basis.  If the tables are not created by someone listed as owner in the \ddp output (user1 or DBA1) then the privileges are not applied.  you have to run the 'ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES' for every individual user.  Either while being logged in as that user, or using the "ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER user1, user2, user3. .." construction.

Comment: @jjanes is there a way to make the app user the owner so it shows on the ddp output?  How would that work?

Comment: @jjanes.  Here is what I understand you saying:

`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER appuser IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly;`

Is this what you are trying to tell me?